# Printing the first 3 digits from the decimals place

Tags: java

Prompt:
Input a double and print the first three digits after the decimal point with a space between them.

Sample run:

Please input a decimal number:
67.3424
Answer: 3 4 2

I'm not sure where to start. With only just learning truncating, numeric casts, modular division, printing and basic maths, How do I get the first 3 digits of any decimal number for ex.
Example 1:
input: 234.555 Output: 555

Example 2:
input: 253.6324673 Output: 632

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class U1_L6_Activity_Three 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //new scanner
    System.out.println("Please input a decimal number: "); //prompts user to input decimal number
//all the math stuff that i dont know how to do

  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "I'm not sure where to start" doesn't make for a great Stack Overflow question. This question isn't so much about a task or concept, as it is about "how do I break down a problem," which is a big and somewhat exploratory question. You should ask your teacher (or teaching assistant, etc) for help, in a situation where you can explore the problem together in a more back-and-forth, interactive format than what this site is designed for.

Comment: With that said, before you even write any Java, ask yourself how you would do this yourself. If I give you a number, "123.4567", you know the answer is "456", right? Well, _how_ do you know that? What steps did you take? Think about them first from a string parsing perspective, and then think about the math behind that. If I asked you to come up with a set of math operations (rounding, division, etc) to turn "123.4567" into "456", what would you do? Once you know how to solve it, hopefully it'll be easier to translate that to code.

Comment: Thats the big thing, I was trying to rack my brain on how to get that answer which is the exact reason why i came here

Comment: I'm able to code it if I knew, I'm sure of it but it's just how to get it is what I'm not sure about

Comment: I'm sorry, but for the reasons I gave in my first comment, this is not a very suitable question for this site. The fact that you're under a time crunch is not a mitigator for that. Here's a small clue to get you started: if you rounded 123.4567 down, you'd get 123, right? If you subtract that from the original, you'd get 0.4567. can you turn that into "456.<something>"?

Comment: What happens if the input number has less than three places after the decimal point? Do you pad with zeros? In other words, does 1.5 become 500? Or should the result be just 5?

Comment: Treat the input as a string, not a number (because it *is* a string): `System.out.println(new Scanner(System.in).next().replaceAll(".*\\.(.)(.)(.).*", "$1 $2 $3"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first subtracting the whole number part from the decimal number, then multiplying the result by 1000 and casting it to an integer. This will give you the first three digits after the decimal point. Here is the code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //new scanner
System.out.println("Please input a decimal number: "); //prompts user to input decimal number

double input = scanner.nextDouble(); //reads the input

int firstThreeDigits = (int)((input - (int)input) * 1000); //gets the first three digits after the decimal point

// Step by step explanation for above
// assuming input is 253.6324673, then:

// (int)input
// (int)253.6324673  - results in 253

//  input - (int)input
//  253.6324673 - 253 - results in 0.6324673

// (input - (int)input) * 1000
// 0.6324673 * 1000 - results in 632.4673

// (int)( 632.4673 ) - finally remove the floating part
// (int)632.4673 - results in 632

System.out.println("Please input a decimal number: " + firstThreeDigits);
```

If you also need spaces between digits, you will need more math:

```
System.out.println("Answer: " + (firstThreeDigits / 100) + 
   " " + (firstThreeDigits / 10 % 10) + " " + (firstThreeDigits % 10));
```

(firstThreeDigits / 100) - this calculates 632/100 which results in 6, because its integer division.

(firstThreeDigits / 10 % 10) - here 632/10 results in 63 and 63 % 10 is a modulo operation. 63 is divided by 10 and the reminder is returned, which is 3.

(firstThreeDigits % 10) - almost same as above, 632 % 10, leaves the last digit which is 2.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... Input a double and print the first three digits after the decimal point with a space between them. ..."*

Simply convert the value to a *String*, and access the character indices via the *[String#charAt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))* method.

```java
String s = String.valueOf(67.3424);
int o = s.indexOf('.') + 1;
s = "%s %s %s".formatted(s.charAt(o++), s.charAt(o++), s.charAt(o));
```

Comment: Did you miss this part of the question? _With only just learning truncating, numeric casts, modular division, printing and basic maths_ Are you sure that your answer adheres to those limitations?

Comment: @Abra, they are learning math.  What did I miss?

Comment: I believe method `indexOf` is not what the OP is looking for. (Probably neither `valueOf` nor `charAt` - but since you're using [String] methods, why not method `next` (of class `Scanner`) rather than `nextDouble` and converting to a String?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small clue to get you started: if you rounded 123.4567 down, you'd get 123, right? If you subtract that from the original, you'd get 0.4567. can you turn that into "456."?
Answered by: yshavit
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1076640/yshavit

Comment: it was from a comment

Answer (score 0):

Try the below function:

```
private int getFirstThreeDecimalValue(double number) {
        int b = (int) number; // output the integer value 121.3211212 -> 121
        return (int) ((number - b) * 1000); // returns the first 3 decimal value i.e. 321 
    }
```

This can be done in one line as below :

```
private int getFirstThreeDecimalValue(double number) {
        return (int)((number - (int) number ) * 1000);
    }
```

Read more on casting from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-double-to-integer-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You only need 2 arithmetic operations:

```
double input = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.println((int)(input * 1000) % 1000);
```